# Ruby check array, return the indexes, which data is exist

Tags: ruby, arrays

How can I check if there's a data that not nil in an array, and then return the index of that data?
Example:

```
myary = [nil, nil, 300, nil, nil] # <= index 2 is 300
```

now is there a method to get the value 2? As we know the index 2 is 300 and not nil.
I need to get the index not the value. And moreover there probably will ot only one element that is not nil, perhaps the array could be like this

```
myotherary = [nil, nil, 300, 400, nil] # <= index 2,3 = 300,400
```

now for this I need to get 2 and 3 value, is this posibble? 
Okay thank you very much, I appreciate all answer.

P.S : Please no flaming, if you don't want to help then just leave, I have spent some time to solve this matter and not succeed. I'm not going to ask here if I can solve it by myself. I had enough of them who not helping, instead asking "what method have you tried?" or write something else that actually not helping but harrasing.

Comment: Sorry I accidentaly delete this post :( 
I have undelete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`map.with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index):

```
myary.map.with_index { |v, i| i if v }.compact
# => [2]
myotherary.map.with_index { |v, i| i if v }.compact
# => [2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use [Enumerable#select](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) in part because it reads well; the word "select" describes what you want to do.

**Code**

For just the indices:

```
def indices_only(arr)
  arr.size.times.select { |i| arr[i] }
end
```

If it would be more useful to return both non-nil values and corresponding indices:

```
def values_and_indices(arr)
  arr.each_with_index.select(&:first)
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr1 = [nil, nil, 300, nil, nil]
arr2 = [nil, nil, 300, 400, nil]

indices_only(arr1)       #=> [2]
indices_only(arr2)       #=> [2, 3]

values_and_indices(arr1) #=> [[300, 2]]
values_and_indices(arr2) #=> [[300, 2], [400, 3]]
```